# Nagios3 "Return code of 127 is out of bounds"

Tags: nagios, ping

Without making any changes to nagios3 config or OS (debian) filesystem changes when I add some extra devices (to the 12000+ on it already) suddenly

```
[1508925621] Warning: Return code of 127 for check of service 'PING' on host 'SOME-HOST.CISCO' was out of bounds. Make sure the plugin you're trying to run actually exists.
[1508925621] SERVICE ALERT: SOME-HOST.CISCO;PING;CRITICAL;HARD;3;(Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)
```

All the binaries are readable/executable none of that has changed since setup.

It happens for ALL hosts of that type, bear in mind this is a setup that's worked for years non-stop  the only thing I can think of is some kind of OS limit is hit when running the checks as that's the only thing that changes, more hosts. 
I've had `max_concurrent_checks=1500` for a long time. (Its a 16 core 24GB RAM physical server)

Apart from the concurrent checks I run

`check_result_reaper_frequency=25`
`max_check_result_reaper_time=20`

The large group of hosts are configured as such:

```
define host{
        use                     generic-cisco
        host_name               SOME_HOST.CISCO
        alias                   SOME_HOST.CISCO
        address                 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        check_command   check-host-alive
        hostgroups              cisco_devices
        }

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               SOME_HOST.CISCO
        service_description     PING
        check_command           check_ping!200.0,20%!600.0,60%
        normal_check_interval   10
        retry_check_interval    5
        }
```

The only thing to make return it to a working state is to take off some of the more recent hosts I've added and stop and start and hope it runs fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens, if you try to execute `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H SOME_HOST.CISCO -w 200.0,20% -c 600.0,60% ; echo $?` as user `nagios`? `echo $?` shows the return code of the last command. I suspect this return code to be `127`. This would indicate that user `nagios` isn't allowed to to send ICMP packages. Hopefully you get a more expressive error message.

Comment: It's fine! Ping OK, working on one reload and not the next that's the mystery

Comment: Happened again even though I changed a bunch of hosts to use check_icmp. And since its in that state I tried the command by hand and yes the command does work still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What fixed it was although I had many other performance recommendations followed I hadn't disabled `enable_environment_macros`
 Not a dent in performance now. Apparently the problem was the OS was struggling with making those environment vars available at that amount of hosts.. 
Found through [here](http://aminastaneh.net/2011-05-22/nagios-error-127-unusual-solution.html)

I like a good nagios facepalm.